# How to create OAuth 2.0 permanent access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Current OAuth2.0 accesstoken is dynamic and generated for every 3396 seconds. I am using few APIs which needs this token to be used as header. Is there any way to create a permanent static accesstoken and store it somewhere so that I don't need to dynamically create one everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use session storage? Check out the session storage live times, ie, when does session storage reset.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

The Access Token is short lived by design. You have three options:-

1. Create a Refresh Token
2. Silently obtain a new access token each hour
3. Use a Service Account

which option is best for you depends on the architecture of your app.